# Drawing SVG PATH using JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to draw An SVG path using javascript:

```
const page = document.getElementById('LAB');
var Erouter = document.createElement("div");
  Erouter.setAttribute("height", "50");
  Erouter.setAttribute("width", "50");
  Erouter.setAttribute("style", " position: relative;");
  Erouter.style.left = Routers[r].x + "px";
  Erouter.style.top = Routers[r].y + "px";
  page.appendChild(Erouter)
  var elem = document.createElement("img");
    elem.setAttribute("src", "./router.png");
    elem.setAttribute("height", "50");
    elem.setAttribute("width", "50");
    elem.setAttribute("style", " position: absolute;");
    elem.setAttribute("alt", "Routers");
    Erouter.appendChild(elem);
  var svg = document.createElement("svg");
  svg.setAttribute("style", " position: absolute;");
  svg.setAttribute("style","border:orange; border-width:5px; border-style:solid;");
  svg.setAttribute("height", "500px");
  svg.setAttribute("width", "500px");

  var link = document.createElement('path');
  link.setAttribute('d','M0 0 ' + 'L150 980');
  link.setAttribute('stroke','green');
  Erouter.appendChild(svg);
  svg.appendChild(link);
```

However, when I check the HTML generated I get the right HTML but nothing shows up on the page.
If I type in the exact same html generated on W3 I get the expected result.

Comment: You need to create SVG elements via namespaced method `createElementNS` e.g `document.createElementNS('https://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg')` otherwise they will be appended as HTML elements and not rendered.

Comment: can you explain this a bit more please

Comment: SVG elements can only "exist" in an appropriate namespace. See Robert Longson's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57894500/why-is-it-necessary-to-use-document-createelementns-when-adding-svg-tags-to)

Answer (score 0):

When you embed `<svg>` into an HTML page, always specify the [`viewBox`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute) attribute:

```html
<svg viewBox="-1 -1 2 2">
  <circle x="0" y="0" r="1"/>
</svg>
<hr>
<svg>
  <circle x="0" y="0" r="1"/>
</svg>
```

The `<svg>` element above the line displays a circle in the rectangle from (-1,-1) to (1,1). The `<svg>` element below the line is invisible.

Comment: svg.setAttribute('viewbox', '0 0 1000 1000');

Comment: still didnt work

Comment: `viewBox`, not `viewbox`.

Comment: yes sorry same problem

Comment: may I point out that only the container is written in the html file, the rest is all from javascript

Comment: If you create the `<svg>` element with Javascript, you must set the `viewBox` attribute with Javascript. Does it work if you simplify your example (without the styles, say)?

Comment: No its doesnt work at all

Comment: Can you edit your question and use the `<>` button (Ctrl+M) to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?